# Bootstrap modal seems to be caching my image every time I dynamically populate it. Is there a way to clear this?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So I am using jquery to grab the url of images in a gallery and dynamically populate bootstrap modal.  It seems to work fine however in some browsers I noticed that when  you close the modal and try to open a different image the old image pops up before loading the new one. After doing some debugging I noticed that each time you open the modal it seems to fire show.bs.modal for each time the modal was previously opened. It seems to be caching each previous image loaded into the modal.  Is there a way to clear this on hidden.bs.modal/hide.bs.modal?

I tried this code but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
       $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
})
```

Here is a codepen to demonstrate what's happening: [Example Code](http://codepen.io/jfunchio/pen/KaJpjj?editors=1010)

If you look at the console you can see what I'm talking about.  Sorry if it's kind of messy I'm am still pretty new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that it only happens on some browsers. Perhaps it's because of the caching properties of the browser itself? What happens when you clear the browser cache?

Comment: Yes, it seems like you can only see it happen on everything but chrome.  However if you look at the console in my codepen you can see it firing 'show.bs.modal' multiple times when you try to open the modal window.  Especially when you open and close it a couple times.